# Copying unicode symbols from Firefox address bar as is

Tags: firefox, unicode, address-bar, i18n

Let's say I open a webpage with some Unicode characters, say, Cyrillic, in the address like this:

> [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Функциональная_закреплённость](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

When I try to copy it from the address bar somewhere else, it becomes unreadable rubbish:

> http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

I guess this is for compatibility. However for readability I want to copy it straight away with proper Unicode characters.

What and how should I tweak to make that possible?

**Edit:** The answers are good, but they are hacky. Are there any settings in `about:config`?

Comment: From the multiple answers, the [easiest way](https://superuser.com/a/480697/89738) seems to be: *Copy only a fragment of the URL*, and more completely: *Don't select the whole URL in the address bar, either exclude one character, or add one (e.g. a space at the end). Then add/remove this character after the paste*.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176661/copying-a-utf-8-url-from-browsers-address-bar-gives-only-the-ugly-encoded-one

Answer (score 30):

The setting was replaced with `browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy` in Firefox 53+. Set it to `true`.

For copying in Firefox on Android see https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224951/17612

Comment: It works only in url-bar, if I just copy link from web-page and past – I still get %-things. Does Firefox have addon like [Chrome's](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp)?

Comment: @stegetsj I'm not aware of such extension, unfortunately. I don't think I'll use it but if you find one and post it as a separate answer I'll definitely upvote it.

Answer (score 17):

Try setting [the `network.standard-url.escape-utf8` option](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.standard-url.escape-utf8) via [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config).

Possible values and their effects:

- `true` - Escape UTF-8 URLs. (Default)
- `false` - Do not escape UTF-8 URLs.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working anymore. I'm using FF28. The option is there but it gives no effect.

Comment: For the record for future visitors, setting `network.standard-url.escape-utf8` to false does seem to work as of FF40.

Comment: This was the default on some version, but was changed because it breaks some websites: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552273

Comment: Works fine in FF 45.

Comment: Changing the setting doesn't do anything in FF 49.

Comment: What's the difference between this setting, and the setting `network.standard-url.encode-utf8`

Comment: Seems to partially work, not for all symbols. In this case enabling flag works for cyrillic symbols, but parentheses are still encoded: `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стеклоомыватель_%28автомобиль%29`

Comment: The setting's name was changed, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1255451/513819).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, browsers do that -- it's URL encoding and actually a quite useful thing.

I see two choices

1. Copy only a *fragment* of the URL, it will not be URL encoded.
2. Decode the URL encoding. In Unix, you can open a terminal, and type

   ```
   echo -n -e "$(echo http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%DB0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C | sed 's/+/ /g;s/%\(..\)/\\x\1/g;')"
   ```

Comment: This should be the default answer.

Comment: Your idea regarding copying a part of the URL is extremely helpful! (especially because on my FF v50.0, the about:config setting did not change anything). Regarding the second option you wrote, Is there a command for Windows users too?

Answer (score 13):

It's not rubbish, it's [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding). However here's the trick:
You can edit the URL in the address bar (by adding and then removing a character), and the copy-pasting should preserve the encoding.

Comment: Why the downvote? oO

Comment: Interesting "trick". Seems to work in `Firefox` v.32, however unfortunately *not* in `Chromium` v.37 (~ `Google Chrome`). Or does it?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty works for me in Chromium 76.

Answer (score 4):

Use this key sequence to copy UTF-8 URL:

```
Ctrl-L, Home(or End), Space(or a letter/symbol), Backspace, Ctrl-L, Ctrl-C
```

Comment: Also works for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the URL from the address bar
2. Paste it [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).
3. Press the **Decode** button.
4. Copy the decoded URL and use it elsewhere.

Comment: Too complex to just copy the URL by Ctrl+L, Ctrl+C without touching the pointing device.

Answer (score 2):

firefox quantum 62.0

```
about:config

browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy: true
```